# PHP form not submitting correctly

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have a form that displays user data based on a query. The form is meant to allow users to update their user account information. i.e., First name, Last name, Email address, etc.

**account.php - form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="fName" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $fName ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="lName" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lName ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="emailAddress" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $emailAddress ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $username ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" name="updateaccount" type="button">
                        <span></span>
                        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**updateaccount.php**

```
<?php

$msg = "";
if(isset($_POST["updateaccount"]))
{
    $fName = $_POST["fName"];
    $lName = $_POST["lName"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $emailAddress = $_POST["emailAddress"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $fName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $fName);
    $lName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $lName);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $emailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailAddress);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
    $password = md5($password);


    $sql="SELECT emailAddress FROM users WHERE emailAddress='$emailAddress'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $msg = "Sorry...This email already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users (fName, lName, username, emailAddress, password)VALUES ('$fName', '$lName', '$username', '$emailAddress, '$password')");
        if($query)
        {
            $msg = "Your account has been updated";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The above code is called on the account.php page:

```
include ("getuseraccount.php");
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using input type button instead of submit for the Update button.  Use 'submit' type instead of 'button' type.
`<input class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" name="updateaccount" type="button">`

try

```
   <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" name="updateaccount" type="submit">
```

Comment: Ugh  I didnt think about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using Ajax to submit the form (which you made no mention of, you need to add the file that you are submitting the form information to.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="updateaccount.php">
```

Comment: Do I still need that if I am including the file? Side note...when I do add the updateaccount.php reference to the action method it still doesnt submit.

Comment: Without knowing what's in the useraccount.php file I can't say for sure where it goes.

It might not be submitting but that could be just another error uncovered. Is the updateaccount.php in the same directory as the form? If not, you'll have to adjust the path in action=

There are any number of other things that could be wrong.